# Brother driver installation wants me to run as root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, printer, brother-printer

The driver install tool from Brother's website [1], has the following instructions (formatting mine):

> 1. Download the tool. (`linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz`)
>
>    - The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
>    - (The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
>    - e.g. `/home/(LoginName)/Download`
> 2. Open a terminal window and go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step.
> 3. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:
>
>    - Command: `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz`
> 4. Get superuser authorization with the "`su`" command or "`sudo su`" command.
> 5. Run the tool:
>
>    - Command: `bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name`
>    - e.g. `bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J880DW`
> 6. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.
>
>    - When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",
>    - For USB Users: Choose N(No)
>    - For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI number.
>    - The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

In step 4, it asks the user to run as root, which is generally not considered to be a safe or recommended practice. If it's possible to answer for this driver install, is it okay to not run as root and just `sudo` necessary commands when asked? Or does it require root?

Secondly, that the instructions assume `bash` is your preferred (or at least, an installed) shell. Is there a difference if I use my preferred shell (namely, `zsh`)? Or does the installer require some `bash`-specific builtins?

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

[1]: **Not creating a link since clicking initiates a download** (`.gz` @ 22.1 kB): http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj615w_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

Comment: The warning about running as root relates to being root for your normal operations (your default user).  Most system-related tasks require you to do them as root.  When you do that in a terminal session, it applies only within that terminal session and disappears when you close the terminal.

Comment: Right, but isn't it better practice still to just `sudo` the necessary commands? I don't think that this as root will cause any file ownership problems, I'm just looking for the recommended practice (and looking to avoid unnecessary/catch-all run as root instructions).

Comment: It's possible that the installer script contains numerous actions that need to be performed as root.  If using sudo was adequate, they would have written the instructions that way.  Typically, commands will simply fail if root is required and they were not executed as root; it won't prompt you for each command.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This constitutes an answer so please feel free to post it. Any idea about the `bash`/`zsh` requirement? Perfectly happy to load up `bash`, just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone would be able to definitively answer the bash/zsh question.  You aren't actually doing user stuff in the shell, just calling it.  You could try zsh, or just load bash if it isn't already there by default.  Your question reminds me of the old saying "anybody can make wine but a chemist".  If you crush grapes, nature will produce wine.  Chemists can't make wine because they insist on tweaking things and introducing "improvements" to the otherwise simple process.  :-)

Comment: `sudo`ing the command should be fine, the whole process tree starting at the spawned `bash` will be `root` so even if it spawns many subcommands, you should be fine. As for `bash` vs. `zsh`, I would advise against trying running a `bash` script with `zsh`. While fairly compatible, they are not the same and the script might rely upon `bash` specific features.

Comment: I have installed a Brother driver on by Ubuntu 16.04, and I guess I just sudo'ed the installator. "Running as root " and "sudo'ing" are synonyms.

Comment: @fixer1234 I like your saying, I'm definitely guilty of that behavior! :) Thanks to all for your input.